# Table inside a modal is being cutoff

Tags: javascript, html, charts, modal-dialog, materialize

i want to have a table inside the modal that shows some data. but when i set the table size to bigger then 1 line(i use a scrollbar, so, bigger than one line each time),my table is being cut. i want to set it as much as it can fit inside the modal so you can see as much rows as possible without scrolling down the scrollbar, but when i set the table height higher thatn 100px it starts to be cut. here is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src = "jquery.js"></script>
    <script src = "Sources/Chart.js"></script>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href = 
"Sources/bootstrap.css">
    <script src = "client.js"></script>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href = 
"Sources/MatirialIcons.css">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href = 
"Sources/Matirialize.css">
    <script type = "text/javascript"
            src = "Sources/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src = "Sources/Matirialize.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-
scale=1">

</head>
<body>
</div>
<button class = "btn waves-effect waves-light red" id = "SendBtn">
    <i class = "material-icons">send</i></button>
<!-- Modal Trigger -->
<a class="waves-effect waves-light red btn modal-trigger" 
href="#modal1">Show Data</a>
<!-- Modal Structure -->
<div id="modal1" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h4>Server's test results</h4>
        <p id = "modalParagraph"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#!" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect 
waves-green btn-flat">Close</a>
        <a href="#modal2" class=" waves-effect waves-light red btn 
modal-trigger">Data</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="modal2" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h4>Data Table</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <div style="overflow:scroll;height:600px;width:100%;">
            <table style="width:100%;height:100%" id = 
"ModalChanTable">
                <tr id = "1">
                    <th>example1</th>
                    <th>example1</th>
                    <th>example1</th>
                </tr>
                <tr id = "2">
                    <th>example2</th>
                    <th>example2</th>
                    <th>example2</th>
                </tr>
                <tr id = "3">
                    <th>example3</th>
                    <th>example3</th>
                    <th>example3</th>
                </tr>
                <tr id = "4">
                    <th>example4</th>
                    <th>example4</th>
                    <th>example4</th>
                </tr>
                <tr id = "5">
                    <th>example5</th>
                    <th>example5</th>
                    <th>example5</th>
                </tr>
                <tr id = "6">
                    <th>example6</th>
                    <th>example6</th>
                    <th>example6</th>
                </tr>
                <tr id = "7">
                    <th>example7</th>
                    <th>example7</th>
                    <th>example7</th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <a href="#!" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect 
waves-green btn-flat">Close</a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this line,if you call model,by default it call the smaller modal but there is a larger one. I guess you use this.

```
<div id="modal1" class="modal modal-lg">//I added modal-lg to the class
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h4>Server's test results</h4>
        <p id = "modalParagraph"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#!" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect 
waves-green btn-flat">Close</a>
        <a href="#modal2" class=" waves-effect waves-light red btn 
modal-trigger">Data</a>
    </div>
</div>
```